# Burninate [android-game]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[android-game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-game) is a somewhat pointless tag, containing about 20 questions.  I'd say it's worth removing.

Comment: As an aside, many of the questions within the tag could use a glance by people with close votes as part of the closer look at the tag.

Comment: While I agree that this is a relatively pointless tag if it's used by 20 questions 20 people thought it was useful. If it seems the chances of it being added back are pretty low then do it, otherwise, if it's likely to be added back then don't bother.

Comment: @MER but there is no [tag:game], [tag:ios-game], [tag:windows-game], [tag:unix-game], etc. A question can be about game programming issue, but we don't need to tag [tag:game] to it as it won't be really helpful (kind of meta tag). Instead, tag the game engine's name, or the service that can be mastered by people there.

Comment: @Andrew T. I'm not suggesting we should definitely keep it just, in the opinion of people (you Pokechu22, probably MichaelT) who have more experience watching the tag trends: if it's likely to be added back then fighting it off isn't worth it, but if it's likely to not be then definitely get rid of it. IMHO

Answer (score 7):

### Burninated the tag!

I have removed the tag from all tagged questions and improving/flagging them at the same time. Now, the question is, do we need to add "**Do not use this tag!**" to the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-game/info)?

Comment: The tag, and it's wiki with it, will be automatically deleted within then next 24 hours.
It is unlikely to attract any new questions before then.
Thus there is no point editing the wiki

Comment: Well isn't the problem more that having both together in one tag is (or should be) redundant. I say this meaning that android & game as separate tags make more sense than having a specific tag, but is it worth preventing people from re-creating it? If it's likely to be re-created just don't burninate...