# ​[game] over. Insert coin to burninate?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, blocklist-request

[game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game) was created sometime yesterday. It has nine questions as I write this post now. I have [not been very successful](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8028120) in removing it from posts as I have less than 2K reputation. Its getting about 8 questions a day. I feel its not a useful tag and more generic than the burninated [[andriod-game]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276161/2246380) tag and we need to burninate it. Can any 2K+ user burninate the tag?

The tag has been burniated for now. As Hans [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294089/burninate-game-game-over?noredirect=1#comment192496_294089) this tag keeps coming back. Can we blacklist the tag?

Comment: Anyone intending to fix these questions should fix *all* the things wrong with the question too.  Just removing the tag isn't ideal (although if the question should be closed, it may be best to leave it alone).

Comment: Jeez, there's a [[jump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jump)] tag as well??

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I did't see that. It has a follower too :P

Comment: Let's hope there's no question at 3 UTC, so the tag will be pruned...

Comment: You are not the only one unsuccessful at removing the tag, it keeps getting burninated [over and over again](http://web.archive.org/web/20131224034715/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game).  The "Don't use this tag!" warning keeps disappearing repeatedly as well :)  So it just keeps coming back, SO users *do* ask questions about games.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for sharing that. I was thinking how such a tag hasn't been created till yesterday. So wasn't the tag blacklisted or something similar?

Comment: Maybe this should be upgraded to a blacklist request D:

Comment: @Braiam I agree. Adding the blacklist request tag

Comment: I just fixed/closed all of the questions with the game tag. Hopefully that does something. If not, at least a few questions were improved.

Comment: @Jojodmo I just read this post and there was already a new question in the tag. I think blacklisting is the only way we'll make progress here.

Comment: New questions are being asked. I have [unsuccessfully tried](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8039185) to update the tag wiki excerpt to mention to not use the tag. Can anyone with tag wiki editing privileges update the tag info?

Comment: @Ram: I have edited it in.

Comment: @nhahtdh that would prove pointless, since the tag wiki/excerpts gets deleted along with the tag.

Comment: @Braiam: The point is to attract some attention from the asker to not to use this tag. I only edited in "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" anyway.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for taking the responsibility and burninating the tag on new questions on regular basis.

Comment: I legitimately left the tab with the tags open and forgot about 'em for a while.  Come back to it while on a break from work and all of a sudden there are questions with that senseless tag there.  Easy enough to clean up and I'm happy to help out.

Comment: On a very serious note, the warning not to use the tag is extremely pointless, as that hasn't stopped anyone from using it.  What we really need is early blacklisting; hopefully something before the cron runs in ~6 hours.

Comment: @Makoto True, I understand it is pointless but if it stops atleast one user from posting a new question  with the tag I am happy with it. Yeah, it needs to be blacklisted fast and I hope the tag gets pruned this time.

Comment: IT'S GONE!  A few questions came up in it late but it's finally gone!

Comment: I must severely criticise you for missing the opportunity to title the question "[game] over" as demanded by common meme practice.

Comment: @deceze "[game] over" is less than the required 15 characters.

Comment: Some creative writing then...! *[game] over – burniation of taglodor!* ;-P

Comment: Cool, edit in the title.

Comment: @deceze Great Job!! Love the title.

Comment: @Jonas Thanks, my spellchecker didn't catch that for some inexplicable reason.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like this tag has finally been removed, so it won't be arbitrarily created again by someone asking a new question.

I'm *completely* in favor of blacklisting this particular tag too so it doesn't manage to sneak back in.

Comment: Thanks, Makoto for your efforts. Hope the tag doesn't get created again before it is blacklisted. Btw How do you know a tag doesn't exist? Both tag with no questions page and the page now look similar.

Comment: The tag summary no longer appears, which is what I was going off of.  Earlier it has that big warning that said "Do not use", and now it doesn't because there's no tag.

Comment: Oh true. I forgot.

Answer (score -14):

I think burninating a tag like this is OK but I feel like a blacklist is not the best solution because the tag may be bad/not constructive now. but this may change in the future.

**Example**: This will probably not happen but you never know!

A new library for c++ is invented by a third party which allows you to create nice animations for terminal games like pong or tetris. This library is called game because the third party which made it feels like it fits the purpose of game making within the terminal.

At that point the game tag is constructive to the site.

ofcourse you could just get rid of the tag in the blacklist but than you need a mod to do that. Can't we just deal with the fact that some people like the game tag in their question?

This tag has been burinated for now but I think that we should not blacklist it. we can however warn users that a tag has been burinated (I don't know if that exists because I never tried using a burinated tag)

Comment: In that case, since the name is very broad, it would be tagged `c++-game`.

Comment: @Kyll the Ncurses libary is also taged 'Ncursers`not `c++-Ncurses`

Comment: By the hypothetical time when this library becomes relevant, the game tag will already be spoiled with hundreds or thousands of questions *not* related to that library.

Comment: @chiccodoro so we should burinate the tag but not blacklist it

Comment: @CoderGuy If we come up with such hypothetical situations for every tag the blacklist option would not exist in the first place. Burninating a tag needs community effort. If the tag keeps coming back like this one it needs to be monitored and burninated regularly which takes even more community effort on regular basis.

Comment: How about we revisit this problem in the future, when the "game" tag could stand on its own as its own entity?  As of right now any questions that are solely about "game" would be closed as being too broad.  Further, there are specific game libraries that have their proper tag and actually *can* stand on their own.

Comment: This is just silly. If we follow this logic, we could never blacklist any tag, because somebody might come up with an on-topic product of the same name.

Comment: @ChrisHayes that's exactly why I think a blacklist is not OK and we should not use it