# ... [game] over: Insert coin to blacklist?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, blocklist-request

[game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game) was created again. It was [already burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294089/game-over-insert-coin-to-burninate), and has currently 64 questions, with only 2 of them have a score > 0.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   No.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   No
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   No.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   No.

So. Should this tag be blacklisted?

Comment: The only way to win at burnination is not to play.

Comment: @RobertColumbia ...you must be new here. The only way to win at burnination is to summon **Trogdor the Burninator to bring fire and damnation upon your foes!** And then blacklist the tag, of course.

Comment: Okay, so apparently we don't want a tag that says its about game development (which is on-topic, by the way). So what about related tags online-game, 2d-games, gametheory and tiles-game?

Comment: @Gimby Is game theory related to game development?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a game itself. How can that tag be off-topic?

Comment: @Gimby It's not about it being to do with games, it's about how generic and ambiguous it is. Tagging something as [tag:game] doesn't really tell you anything about the question itself.

Comment: @jwg I may have been a tad overzealous when picking tags I found simply by searching "game" :) I already filtered out game-ai and game-physics because they seem to be specific enough (or are they? I get confused by what people tend to find burn-worthy).

Comment: Re-burnination () then blacklisting is the correct process to [game] the system.

Comment: @Gimby This has been brought up time and again. It's called a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and you burninate it

Comment: Are there any queries for most downvoted tags?

Comment: Actually, 9 questions tagged `[game]` score above 0. Not sure where you got the `2` from. Still: Kill it with fire!

Comment: @PasserBy thats not a meta tag, but it is ambiguous, that's why it was deleted. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360795/is-it-game-over-for-gaming?rq=1

Comment: Did the meta effect kick in, already 84 questions now...

Comment: @Siguza This made my day. But yes, this is the only real way to burninate.

Comment: @Cerbrus Interestingly, I find 10 with a score above 0 with [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgame%5D+score%3A1+is%3Aquestion). Maybe some meta effect.

Comment: @Cerbrus And I find 84 questions, not 64 questions.

Comment: @TinyGiant I think it a meta tag when you can't conceivably have an on-topic question with it alone. What does [tag:game] as a single tag tells you? Game design?

Comment: That is absolutely not what a meta tag is. Meta-tags _["do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.).](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)_. What you're talking about is an _off-topic_ tag. And contrary to your claims, questions about programming games are on-topic, it's just that the tag is too ambiguous to be useful. @PasserBy

Comment: @TinyGiant The only way it is on-topic is when it describes that a problem came from something game related, but not the problem itself. It is off-topic otherwise.

Comment: @Passerby uh where did you get that? We have tags for gaming engines and other concepts related to game programming. Questions about programming games are absolutely not inherently off-topic and whoever told you that is lying to you. It just so happens that this tag is too ambiguous because the tag itself is ambiguous, not because programming games is somehow the one programming topic that is not allowed. That would be absurd.

Comment: @TinyGiant consider a question only tagged [tag:game]. What is that question about? What skill set do you probably need to have to answer that question? By contrast, if a question is tagged [tag:unity3d], and you have a good understanding how unity3d works, where to find things in the API and have a good mental concept of it, then you can probably answer most of the questions right away or scratch your head and say "well, that's an interesting question, I will think about it". And that's the difference between a useful tag and a meta tag.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn that is absolutely 100% _**not**_ what a meta tag is. Im done repeating myself. Read the goddamn definition I linked if you want to continue this discussion, otherwise stop wasting my time. Saying, "i think this apple is a pear because i feel it is a pear" does not make the apple a pear.

Comment: To be fair both of you are using different aspects of Jeff Atwood's description of meta tags from his blog post linked by Tiny.

Comment: fine, answer that simple question for me: What is a question only tagged with [tag:game] about? Or does it just describe an aspect of the question (has something to do with games)?

Comment: @TylerH note that the list is just an example, not an exclusive list where everything else is not a meta-tag.

Comment: Im not arguing for keeping the tag. The tag should die a quick death. Im arguing against the appropriation of the term meta-tag to mean "any tag I don't like" as opposed to the actual definition of the term. No I'm not going to get into irrelevant hypotheticals that have absolutely nothing to do with your argument. I dont want to keep that tag at all, i want people to know what the terms they are using mean before they use them and to know when they should in fact use them.

Comment: Interesting. You say "I won't answer your question". You did not bring up a reference for a definition that would not include [game] as a meta-tag. Instead, I used your reference to the blog post to argue that it says exactly that: "If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag." I asked you the questions so you can show that this is not the case here, therefore this is not a meta tag. But instead you decided to discard my questions as irrelevant. I have my own answers to my questions, and therefore concluded that this tag is a meta tag.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I say burninate and blacklist, as nothing has changed since the last time [game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game) was burninated. In addition to the reasons you listed in your question, the following also apply:

- I can't be an expert at such a broad topic as 'games', in general, and certainly not in any way that relates to Stack Overflow's topicality.
- Whether you are writing code for a game program or for a non-game program is not relevant to the code itself, or the problem you are facing (if it is, then your question probably belongs on [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)).
- Questions involving programming applications or engines built specifically for games will have more specific tags (that typically are mutually exclusive), such as [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), [unreal-engine4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-engine4), or [amazon-lumberyard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-lumberyard).